why that combination of radicals 警 means - police?
One the most lingering questions in my Chinese journey - why a certain combination of radicals result in a particular word. Here is the strangest one = “police”  警 – how on earth => grass + a wrapped mouth + to knock + a speech -> can be perceived all together as “police” ? Is there any logic ? or it is - as it is, just take it and nail into your memory board

You have it backwards. Spoken language came first, written language hints at spoken language. 警 hints at a spoken word jǐng, to warn, by using a similar-sounding character 敬 (jìng), and a meaning hint 言 (speech). Characters are not made up of radicals, radicals are dictionary headings for the sole purpose of organising characters under dictionaries, and have no other purpose.

警 has the meaning of "alert"
Example:
警(alert) + 告 (announce; tell) = 警告 (warn)
警(alert) + 號( horn) = 警號 (siren)

敬/Jìng/ is the phonic component of 警/Jǐng/. (the meaning of 敬 itself is irreverent)

言(words) is the semantic component of 警 (words are used to alert people)


察 means notice; investigate
警察 (alert and investigate) is the job of the police, 警 means police when it is acting as a shorthand for 警察

many thanks indeed :)

The character 警 is a typical 形声字。 There are some examples of 形声字 on the website 形声字
The meaning of 形 in 形声字 is the category (类别)， not the shape (形状)。 For example, 花 is in the category of 草。 The original meaning of 警 is a warning, which belongs to the category of 语言。
The meaning of 声 in 形声字 does not have to be the exact pronunciations (the same initial, the same final, and the same tone). For example, 警 is the tone 3 and 敬 is 4. Some times it just provides the same final. For example, 草 and 早 have the same final of ao.

I suggest familiarizing yourself with "六書" - "the six ways of making Chinese characters (in ancient times)" or "the six categories of Chinese characters". It includes 1. 象形(xiàngxíng; 'form imitation'), 2. 指事(zhǐshì; 'indication'), 3. 會意(huìyì; 'joined meaning'), 4. 假借(jiǎjiè; 'borrowing'), 5. 形声(xíngshēng; 'form and sound'), and 6. 转注(zhuǎn zhù; 'reciprocal meaning').
Piggyback on @dROOOze's comment:
警 belongs to the category of 会意字. It is made up of the two characters "敬" and "言", with "戒敕/告诫(caution/admonish)" as its original meaning. Note that the word "敬" has the meaning of "谨慎(be prudent/discreet)", combined with "言", the resulting word "慎言" implies caution, warning, and alerting.

Characters (字) and character components (部件) are not words (詞). This is incredibly confusing terminology that will only lead to conceptual mistakes later down the line.

Not really. The 會意 class means you can tell the meaning of the characters by just looking at them, such as 上 and 下. I would say 警 isn't in that category.

@fatpenguin 會意字，是指用兩個及兩個以上的獨體漢字，根據各自的含義所組合成的一個新漢字 https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E6%9C%83%E6%84%8F%E5%AD%97/7146699
